Problem to pass contextvars to logging.handlers.QueueListener in Python
I'm trying to parallelize logs with Queuehandler and Queuelistener in a fastapi application but the contextvars setted on the main thread does not propagate to "_monitor" thread of the QueueListener.
To contextualize, I set se contextVar on fastapi main file:
@app.middleware("http")
async def set_context_vars(request: Request, call_next: Callable) -> Any:

    ...
    log_extras.set(extra_logs)

    ...
    response = await call_next(request)

    ...

And use in it in a Formatter on a logger file.
class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:

        ...
        formatted = {
            ...
        }

        formatted.update(log_extras.get())
        return json.dumps(formatted)

Can anyone help me to understand how can I resolve this?

I faced same problem, trying to make non-blocking, Queuehandler/Queuelistener based logging for async django project, at the same time using contextvars to pass data to log records through logging.Filter. The data just don't seem to appear.

I recommend creating a custom class that inherits from QueueHandler and override the prepare method. This will allow you to preserve your contextvars data before placing the LogRecord in the queue. In Python 3.12, the LogRecords are processed in a separate thread by the QueueListener, and since contextvars are not shared between threads, this step is necessary so your JsonFormatter could retain this data.
Something like this
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler
from logging import LogRecord


class ContextVarsHappyHandler(QueueHandler):
    def prepare(self, record: LogRecord) -> LogRecord:
        record = super().prepare(record)
        try:
            extra = log_extras.get()
        except LookupError:
            # sometimes we log from background tasks, etc...
            # so contextvars are not set
            # To avoid explicit checks I decided just to use try-except here
            extra = {}
        record.ctx_extra = extra
        return record


class JsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> str:
        if hasattr(record, 'ctx_extra'):
           ... add data to resulting json


